# php-fpm & Apache 2 - analysing PHP Message: logs

Tags: php-fpm, log-files, awk

One of my servers has recently been switched to using php-fpm.

The error logs now log 404's in a new format:

```
[Sun Dec 26 00:11:37.827426 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 25239:tid
140600822003456] [client 66.249.66.136:37676] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: File
does not exist: /ads.txt'
[Sun Dec 26 00:14:53.732771 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24741:tid
140601015035648] [client 207.46.13.93:9600] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: File
does not exist: /events/view/id/633/supercharge'
```

I previously used a command-line script (using `awk`), written by one of my colleagues many years ago, to parse the logs and extract the URLs that were 404ing and then did some manual excel work to get a tally of any addresses that were erroring but receiving a reasonable number of requests. I'm reasonably comfortable (with the awk manual) to update this script...

But, before I jump in and start editing this script I was suspecting there must be a better way to parse these large log files. Any suggestions for a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending all requests through `proxy_fcgi`. If you have `php` files on the same host then you can use `mod_rewrite` to check if a file exists before sending requests through `proxy_fgci`. This way you can get normal `404`s back.

Comment: Good suggestion if the files existed in the file system - but as it's a CMS site PHP has to make the decisions as to whether a matching page exists in this case.